# How do I add a column that displays the number of distinct rows to this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't know how to ask my question clearly so I'll just show you the money.

To start with, here's a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE sandbox (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    callsign text NOT NULL,
    this text NOT NULL,
    that text NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE sandbox_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE sandbox_id_seq OWNED BY sandbox.id;

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('sandbox_id_seq', 14, true);

ALTER TABLE sandbox ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('sandbox_id_seq'::regclass);

INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (1, 'alpha', 'foo', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:51:09.897579+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (2, 'alpha', 'foo', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:51:36.108867+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (3, 'bravo', 'bar', 'quxx', '2010-12-29 16:52:36.370507+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (4, 'bravo', 'foo', 'quxx', '2010-12-29 16:52:47.584663+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (5, 'charlie', 'foo', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:53:00.742356+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (6, 'delta', 'foo', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:53:10.884721+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (7, 'alpha', 'foo', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:53:21.242904+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (8, 'alpha', 'bar', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:54:33.318907+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (9, 'alpha', 'baz', 'quxx', '2010-12-29 16:54:38.727095+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (10, 'alpha', 'bar', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:54:46.237294+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (11, 'alpha', 'baz', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:54:53.891606+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (12, 'alpha', 'baz', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:55:39.596076+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (13, 'alpha', 'baz', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:55:44.834019+00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (14, 'alpha', 'foo', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:55:52.848792+00');

ALTER TABLE ONLY sandbox
    ADD CONSTRAINT sandbox_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Here's the current SQL query I have:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT ON (this, that)

        id, this, that, timestamp
    FROM
        sandbox
    WHERE
        callsign = 'alpha'
            AND
        CAST(timestamp AS date) = '2010-12-29'
)
    playground
ORDER BY
    timestamp
DESC
```

This is the result it gives me:

```
id      this    that    timestamp
-----------------------------------------------------
14      foo     qux     2010-12-29 16:55:52.848792+00
13      baz     corge   2010-12-29 16:55:44.834019+00
11      baz     qux     2010-12-29 16:54:53.891606+00
10      bar     qux     2010-12-29 16:54:46.237294+00
9       baz     quxx    2010-12-29 16:54:38.727095+00
8       bar     corge   2010-12-29 16:54:33.318907+00
7       foo     corge   2010-12-29 16:53:21.242904+00
```

This is what I want to see:

```
id      this    that    timestamp                       count
-------------------------------------------------------------
14      foo     qux     2010-12-29 16:55:52.848792+00   3
13      baz     corge   2010-12-29 16:55:44.834019+00   2
11      baz     qux     2010-12-29 16:54:53.891606+00   1
10      bar     qux     2010-12-29 16:54:46.237294+00   1
9       baz     quxx    2010-12-29 16:54:38.727095+00   1
8       bar     corge   2010-12-29 16:54:33.318907+00   1
7       foo     corge   2010-12-29 16:53:21.242904+00   1
```

EDIT:

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0.* (if that helps any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have postgre installed, but I did this on SQL Server, I think you can use the idea:

```
CREATE TABLE sandbox (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    callsign varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    this varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    that varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    tm datetime NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (1, 'alpha', 'foo', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:51:09');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (2, 'alpha', 'foo', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:51:36');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (3, 'bravo', 'bar', 'quxx', '2010-12-29 16:52:36');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (4, 'bravo', 'foo', 'quxx', '2010-12-29 16:52:47');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (5, 'charlie', 'foo', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:53:00');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (6, 'delta', 'foo', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:53:10');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (7, 'alpha', 'foo', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:53:21');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (8, 'alpha', 'bar', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:54:33');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (9, 'alpha', 'baz', 'quxx', '2010-12-29 16:54:38');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (10, 'alpha', 'bar', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:54:46');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (11, 'alpha', 'baz', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:54:53');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (12, 'alpha', 'baz', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:55:39');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (13, 'alpha', 'baz', 'corge', '2010-12-29 16:55:44');
INSERT INTO sandbox VALUES (14, 'alpha', 'foo', 'qux', '2010-12-29 16:55:52');

    SELECT  max(id), this, that, min(tm), COUNT(*)
    FROM sandbox
    WHERE
        callsign = 'alpha'
      AND
        CAST(tm AS date) = '2010-12-29'
    GROUP BY this, that
    ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
```

Output:

```
14  foo qux 2010-12-29 16:51:09.000 3
13  baz corge   2010-12-29 16:55:39.000 2
11  baz qux 2010-12-29 16:54:53.000 1
10  bar qux 2010-12-29 16:54:46.000 1
9   baz quxx    2010-12-29 16:54:38.000 1
8   bar corge   2010-12-29 16:54:33.000 1
7   foo corge   2010-12-29 16:53:21.000 1
```

Comment: This certainly works. I can see that you used aggregate functions on `id` and `tm` to make it possible to use `GROUP BY`. In situations like these when do you use one over the other? For instance why did you use `max` on `id` or does it not make a difference?

Comment: I generally prefer group by because it's more deterministic.  With distinct on you can random answers for the not-distinct on items in the select list.  Also, in PostgreSQL group by is more highly optimizable by the query planner than distinct on.  For larger sets the performance difference can be pretty big.

Comment: @Scott Marlowe: I agree, it is more deterministic. What prevented me from using it was not knowing how to get around the aggregate function error especially when I didn't want the values it threw errors on grouped. The use of `min` and `max` seems to get around this but I'm not sure how it works exactly.

Comment: @Fake Code Monkey Rashid - The max or min is going to take either the max or min value from the group. It looked to me like you were taking the max ID (e.g. 14 for 'foo') which is why I used max on ID. I used min on the tm column to get the earliest records back first. You can change this however you'd like, but the main thing to remember is that any column in which you aren't doing an aggregate on has to be in the group by.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

dcp solution works. Tested it on postgres.

BTW, you should avoid timestamp as a column name since it is a reserved word and needs to be quoted.

Comment: This will throw a `column * must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` error for `id` and `timestamp`. Resolving it will then completely skewer the results.

Comment: Can't you replace the `*` with `that`, giving you a count of the grouped `that`?